# .net core get GetUserManager from ApplicationUser out of constructor

Tags: c#

I am reading current user

```
private async Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUser()  
        {  
            return await _manager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);  
        }
```

but I would like to get UserManager also and read some other data.

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
```

is it possible to get UserManager from ApplicationUser? But not in constructor.

Comment: you can inject UserManager in the constructor of controller

Comment: what about constructor, how to Inject it?

Comment: updated the answer with constructor, using UserManager<ApplicationUser> as an argument

Answer (score 1):

You can inject userManager to any controller like this. And then user manager whenever needed.

```
public class AnyController : Controller
{   
    public AnyController (UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async void GetCurrentUserId()
    {
       var user=await _userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about constructor, how to Inject it?

Comment: public AnyController (UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
when you use UserManager is as an argument to constructor dot net core will do the injection for you.