# Inject User Credentials from HttpRequestContext into the service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I have a .NET 4.6 WebApi 2.0 OWIN App that serves HTTP Requests.
Those requests are authenticated and we are storing certain claims in the RequestContext ClaimsIdentity (UserId, Client Code)

We also have our Controllers, Services and Repository structure.

Our Services are injected into the Controllers via Ninject, and the Repositories into the Services.

When the user performers certain requests we need to check their permissions. The service usually needs to know the: UserId, ClientCode, Groups the user has access to and permissions under each group (Read, Write, etc). This last one is only being stored in a DataBase.

The current flow when executing a request is: obtain the userId and clientCode from the RequestContext claims, use that userid to obtain the Group permissions from the DataBase. Create an object `UserCredentials` with those properies.

This object is then passed on to the Service instances **after** they were injected
This is an example:

```
public PeopleController(IPeopleService peopleService, IUserManagementService userManagementService)
    {
        var clientCode = RequestContext.GetClientCode();
        var userId = RequestContext.GetUserId();
        var permissions = userManagementService.GetUserPermissions(userId, clientCode);
        }

        peopleService.InjectCredentials(new services.Models.UserCredentials()
        {
            ClientCode = clientCode,
            UserId = UserId,
            Permissions = UserPermissions

        });
        _peopleService = peopleService;
    }
```

This doesn't look very elegant to us as we need to repeat that code everywhere and makes the IPeopleService dependant that the user doesn't forget to call the InjectCredentials method.

So my question is, how can I make that UserCredentials class Injectable so it can be passed as a parameter to the IPeopleService constructor?

The main block is that it depends on the HttpRequestContext which is only available on the Controller itself

Thanks

EDIT: I know UserCredentials object can be also be passed as a parameter to each service Method  (which is actually better than the InjectCredentials method)

Comment: did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49921240/3613702

Comment: Can you try my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Injecting the Model, 
In your IUserManagementService implementation inject IHttpContextAccessor. Then implement a method to do what you would do in the controller.
Let this method be responsible for fetching user details for you.

```
public class UserManagementService : IUserManagementService 
{
   private readonly IHttpContext httpContext;

   public UserManagementService (IHttpContext httpContext)
   {
      this.httpContext = httpContext;
   }



   public UserCredentials GetUserDetails()
   {

new services.Models.UserCredentials()
    {
        ClientCode = clientCode,
        UserId = UserId,
        Permissions = UserPermissions

    });
   }

}
```

Finally, inject this service in any other service where you need these details.

```
PeopleController(IPeopleService peopleService, IUserManagementService userManagementService)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention but I am on .net 4.6 From what I have seen  the IHttpContextAccessor is only available on .NET Core

Comment: Oh, But then did you try injecting HttpContext instead of HttpContextAccessor

Comment: But then that should theNinject bind be for the HttpContext during Startup?

Comment: What is the equivalent of HttpRequextContext in Net Core?

Comment: HttpContext.Request should work. @KarthicG

Comment: Then IHttpContextAccessor is not a replacement of HttpRequextContext, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way that is possible, but I don't think its recommended due to the use of HttpContext.Current.user

```
kernel.Bind<UserCredentials>().ToMethod(CreateUserCredentials);


private static UserCredentials CreateUserCredentials(IContext arg)
    {
        var identity = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

        int userId = identity.Identity.GetUserId();
        string clientCode = identity.Identity.GetClientCode();
        var userManagementService = kernel.Get<IUserManagementService>();
        if (userId != 0)
        {
            var permisssions = userManagementService.GetUserPermissions(userId, userType, clientCode);
        }
        return new UserCredentials()
        {
            ClientCode = clientCode,
            UserId = userId,
            Permissions = userManagementService.GetUserPermissions(userId, clientCode)
        };

    }
```

Now the UserCredentials object can be added to constructors as a parameter and will properly intialised.